# how can i pass a string array through a button from one activity to another?

Tags: java, android

```
String[] charc={"FLash","ARROW","SUPERGIRL","BATMAN","SUPERMAN","ATOM","AQUAMAN","CYBORG","JOKER","BANE","GREENLANTERN","ZOOM","REVERSEFLASH","FIRESTORM"};
    private String s;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onCreate was Called",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idList);
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Btn);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,charc);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {

                        s=charc[i];
                b.setText(s);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item Clicked: "+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    public void btnclick(View v){

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, approutes.list.Display.class)
                .putExtra("Flash",s));

    }
```

Comment: you can use intent to pass data from one activity o another

Answer (score 3):

Intent accept String array

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("string", array);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your receiving intent you need to do:

```
Intent i = getIntent();  
string_array = i.getStringArrayListExtra("string");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

From Your first Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, FirstActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("string-array", charc);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Then In Next Activity Get it Like this in on `Create()`

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String [] stringArray = intent.getStringArrayExtra("string-array");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("list_as_string", charc);
startActivity(intent);
```

along with these you should add your SecondActivity in Manifest as Activity and make sure you have added btnclick() method to button in xml layout or you can set button click with following

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // call intent here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data between activities there is `Intent` object. You should do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("charc", charc);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

And to get `charc` in `NextActivity` do:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    char[] charc = intent.getStringExtra("charc");
```